# Access to functions of defined class from it's nested created object

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to access functions of class from it's nested object that's created with `Ext.create` i can't use this because it refer to created object.

```
Ext.define('FM.view.HistoryProperty',{
extend: 'Ext.grid.property.Grid',
alias: 'widget.historyProperty',
title: 'History',
closable: false,
header: true,
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'left'
},
sortableColumns: false,
customEditors: {
    Vehicle: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{
        store: Ext.create('FM.store.Vehicles',{}),
        editable : false,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'vehiclename',
        valueField: 'vehicleid',
        id: 'vehicle'
    }),
    getStartDateField: function() {
        if (!this.startDate) {
            this.startDate = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
                format: 'y-m-d G:i',
                value : this.yesterday(),
                listeners: {
                    expand: {
                        fn: function(field) {
                            field.setMaxValue(this.endDate.getValue());
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return this.startDate;
    } ,
    getEndDateField: function(){
        if(!this.endDate){
            this.endDate = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
                format: 'y-m-d G:i',
                selectOnFocus:true,
                value : this.today(),
                listeners: {
                    expand: {
                        fn: function(field){ field.setMinValue(this.startDate.getValue()); }
                    },
                    scope: this
                }
            });
        }
        return this.endDate;
    }
},
yesterday: function(){
    var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
    yesterday.setHours(0,0,0);
    return yesterday;
},
today: function(){
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(23,59,59);
    return today;
},
source: {
    "Vehicle": 'Select Vehicle',
    "getStartDateField": this.yesterday,
    "getEndDateField": this.today
}
```

});

I use name of defined class to access it's functions but it doesn't work.also `Ext.cmp('historyProperty')` doesn't work!.

Comment: Please give a usage example.

Comment: Is my example code ambiguous? I want to set value in startDate DateField to returned value from historyProperty yesterday function!

Comment: `FM.view.HistoryProperty.endDate.getValue()` won't work because `FM.view.HistoryProperty` is a *class definition*, not an instance of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a field object (or any kind of non primitive value) on the class prototype like you are doing is a very bad idea. Every `HistoryProperty` you instantiate from the class will share that same field which is almost certainly not what you want.

Adding a accessor method for you field and creating it upon the first request allows you to call the yesterday method defined in your class and also makes sure you'll avoid any surprises that might occur with two instances of `HistoryProperty` sharing the same date fields.

```
Ext.define('FM.view.HistoryProperty',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.property.Grid',
    alias: 'widget.historyProperty',

    getStartDateField: function() {
        if (!this.startDate) {
            this.startDate = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
                format: 'y-m-d G:i',
                value : this.yesterday(),
                listeners: {
                    expand: {
                        fn: function(field) {
                            field.setMaxValue(this.endDate.getValue());
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return this.startDate;
    },

    yesterday: function(){
        var yesterday = new Date();
        yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
        yesterday.setHours(0,0,0);
        return yesterday;
    }
});
```

With your current code, the `HistoryProperty.yesterday` method is not available when you are calling it because the class has not yet been defined and you are already trying to access a method on its prototype. Your expand listener handler probably won't work either, assuming the endDate field is created like StartDate. Those fields are on the prototype of the class and need to be accessed like this.

```
function() {
    this.setMaxValue(FM.view.HistoryProperty.prototype.endDate.getValue());
}
```

If you insist on putting the fields directly on your prototype (don't do this), you'll have to define your yesterday function before defining the class. For example.

```
(function() {
    var yesterday = function() {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
        date.setHours(0, 0, 0);
        return date;
    };

    Ext.define('FM.view.HistoryProperty',{
        extend: 'Ext.grid.property.Grid',
        alias: 'widget.historyProperty',
        StartDate: Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
            format: 'y-m-d G:i',
            value : yesterday()
        })
    });
} ());
```

*Edit*

When you are defining a class using `Ext.define`, `this` does not refer to your class prototype unless you are actually inside a class method.

```
Ext.define('Test', {
    doSomething: function() {
        // 'this' refers to the object this method was called on. An instantiation
        // of the Test class.
        this.x = 1; 
    }
    property1: 'a',
    // 'this' is the whatever scope Ext.define was called in (probably window), not Test.prototype.
    property2: this.property1, // property2 will not be 'a'
    objectProperty: {
        // 'this' is still window, not Test.prototype.
        property3: this.property1 // property3 will not be 'a' 
    }
});
```

In your code, the source object literal is referring to `this.yesterday` and `this.today`. You cannot access `yesterday` or `today` at that point in the process of defining your class because `this` is still `window`.

One major issue is that you are using configurations that are meant for class instantiation but are specifying them at class definition time. If you look at Ext's docs for customEditors (which is deprecated), source, sourceConfig, etc. You'll see that they are adding these properties in the configuration object passed in to the constructor.

You don't really want to be adding those properties on the class prototype since they are instance specific and sharing your editor fields across multiple grids will cause a lot of unexpected behavior.

For example, if the start and end date fields are global, changing the start date in one grid will affect the minimum end date in every other grid that shares the fields.

Instead, override the initComponent method and add the config properties there. Something like this should work for you:

```
Ext.define('FM.view.HistoryProperty', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.property.Grid',
    alias: 'widget.historyProperty',
    title: 'History',
    closable: false,
    header: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'left'
    },
    sortableColumns: false,

    getStartDateField: function() {
        if (!this.startField) {
            this.startField = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
                format: 'y-m-d G:i',
                listeners: {
                    expand: {
                        fn: function(field) {
                            // get this instance of the grid's end date field
                            field.setMaxValue(this.getEndDateField().getValue());
                        },
                        // the scope is the grid component.
                        scope: this
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return this.startField;
    },

    getEndDateField: function() {
        if (!this.endField) {
            this.endField = Ext.create('Ext.form.DateField',{
                format: 'y-m-d G:i',
                listeners: {
                    expand: {
                        fn: function(field) {
                            // get this instance of the grid's start date field
                            field.setMinValue(this.getStartDateField().getValue());
                        },
                        // the scope is the grid component.
                        scope: this
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return this.endField;
    },

    getVehicleField: function() {
        return Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{
            store: Ext.create('FM.store.Vehicles',{}),
            editable : false,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'vehiclename',
            valueField: 'vehicleid',
            id: 'vehicle'
        });
    },

    // Setup the source and sourceConfig properties in initComponent not on the
    // class prototype so that each instance of the grid has its own unique
    // setup.
    initComponent: function() {
        // 'this' is the grid component.
        Ext.apply(this, {
            source: {
                Vehicle: "select vehicle",
                startDate: this.yesterday(),
                endDate: this.today()
            },
            sourceConfig: {
                startDate: {
                    displayName: 'Start',
                    // we are in a method so 'this' is the instance of the grid
                    // and the getStartDateField is available to us here.
                    editor: this.getStartDateField()   
                },
                endDate: {
                    displayName: 'End',
                    editor: this.getEndDateField()
                },
                Vehicle: {
                    displayName: 'Vehicle',
                    editor: this.getVehicleField()
                }
            }
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    yesterday: function() {
        var yesterday = new Date();
        yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
        yesterday.setHours(0,0,0);
        return yesterday;
    },

    today: function() {
        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(23,59,59);
        return today;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your best answer. I have question about your answer: what is scope: this in your code?  
Before you answer to my question i defined var yesterday before HistoryProperty and use it in HistoryProperty in my code is it bad idea?

Comment: I edited my code after your answer but it doesn't work i can't see startDate and endDate in historyProperty view!  
You can see my edited code in my question code.

Comment: I think that if i know how can i define private var in this code every thing OK!

Comment: Javascript is very flexible so there are a lot of ways to accomplish the same thing. There's nothing inherently wrong with defining functions outside an Ext.define and then calling them when the class is defined. Sometimes it's the best solution. But in this case, you're running into problems because you're putting properties on the class prototype that really shouldn't be there. I personally think that if you really want to add 'static' properties to a class (like what you were doing before) you should add an explict `statics` block for them.

Comment: I've edited my answer to take into account the new code you posted.

Comment: In your edited code i replaced `sourceConfig:` with  `customEditors:` and it's appropriate config. because `sourceConfig:` doesn't work properly!. If you be like you can edit your code

Comment: Your skill in extjs4 surprised me can you tell me how can improve my skill in javascript and extjs4 like you? Thanks for your best answer.

Comment: You're probably using a version of Ext before 4.1.2. sourceConfig was added in that version. I'd say the best way to improve your skills is to read (and write) a lot of code. The great thing about JavaScript frameworks is that you can always get the source and learn from it. When you're using an Ext component, don't just read the docs for it. View the source code and try to understand what's actually going on. Look for common patterns. See how they handle 'this' and scope (probably the trickiest part of JavaScript). Pop open your debugger and step through code. Experiment in the console.